# Can I do any analysis on spacy display using NER?

Tags: pandas, nlp, location, spacy, named-entity-recognition

When accessing this display in spacy NER, can you add the found entities - in this case any tweets with GPE or LOC - to a new dataframe or do any further analysis on this topic? I thought once I got them into a list I could use geopy to visualive it possibly, any thoughts?

```
colors = {'LOC': 'linear-gradient(90deg, ~aa9cde, #dc9ce7)', 'GPE' : 'radial-gradient(white, blue)'}
options = {'ents' : ['LOC', 'GPE'],'colors':colors} 
spacy.displacy.render(doc, style='ent',jupyter=True, options=options, )
```

Answer (score 0):

The entities are accessible on the `doc` object. If you want to get all the ents in the `doc` object into a list, simply use, `doc.ents`. For example:

```
import spacy
content = "Narendra Modi is the Prime Minister of India"
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
doc = nlp(content)
print(doc.ents)
```

should output:

```
(Narendra Modi, India)
```

Say, you want to the text (or mention) of the entity and the label of the entity (say, PERSON, GPE, LOC, NORP, etc.) then you can get them as follows:

```
print([(ent, ent.label_) for ent in doc.ents])
```

should output:

```
[(Narendra Modi, 'PERSON'), (India, 'GPE')]
```

You should be able to use them in other places as you see fit.